# A SELECT INTO statement cannot contain a SELECT statement that assigns values to a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a stored procedure or function to find the number of null values in each column in a table.

I am having problems determining the syntax for converting the code to a stored procedure/function.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SQL = (
    SELECT '
    ' +
    STUFF((
        SELECT ', [' + c.name + '] = ' + CASE WHEN c.is_nullable = 0 THEN '0' ELSE 'COUNT(*) - COUNT([' + c.name + '])' END
        FROM sys.columns c
        WHERE c.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, 'SELECT ''' + SCHEMA_NAME(o.[schema_id]) + '.' + o.name + ''', COUNT(*), ') + '
    FROM [' + SCHEMA_NAME(o.[schema_id]) + '].[' + o.name + ']'
    FROM sys.objects o
    WHERE o.[type] = 'U'
        AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0
        AND [name] = 'BSEG'
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
INTO xzy
PRINT @SQL
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

I want to stored the results in a table. But I am getting the following error message:

```
Msg 194, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
A SELECT INTO statement cannot contain a SELECT statement that assigns values to a variable.
```

So my ultimate aim is to have a stored procedure/function which upon execution will give number of null values in each column in a table and the results will be stored in another result table.

Comment: isn't this MSSQL?

Comment: I don't see a `select into` in your code...

Comment: --INTO xzy.
I have commented out the into.
Basically I want to store the result in a table. but not being able to determine the syntax

Comment: Hi James! Yes, it is MSSQL, but for some reason this tag is not getting saved in m post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check with this following changes-

Remove assigning part from your query and just use the simple select statement as-

```
SELECT '' +
STUFF((
...

--Note: Write the SQL in such way so that only SQL 
--text from STUFF functions is returned. There is no 
--requirement of assigning the text first to variable @SQL
```

Add INSERT before INTO key as below-

```
...
INSERT INTO xzy
...
```

If still no luck, please provide output of PRINT @SQL command with above 2 changes.

Answer (score -1):

The "INTO xyz" should go above "FROM sys.objects o"?

EDIT
Try this

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SQL = (
    SELECT '
    ' +
    STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + CASE WHEN c.is_nullable = 0 THEN '0' ELSE 'COUNT(*) - COUNT([' + c.name + '])' END + ' AS [' + c.name + ']'
        FROM sys.columns c
        WHERE c.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, 'SELECT ''' + SCHEMA_NAME(o.[schema_id]) + '.' + o.name + ''' as TableName, COUNT(*) as Cnt, ') + '
    INTO xzy
    FROM [' + SCHEMA_NAME(o.[schema_id]) + '].[' + o.name + ']'
    FROM sys.objects o
    WHERE o.[type] = 'U'
        AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0
        AND [name] = 'BSEG' 
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
PRINT @SQL
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: I'm also not sure they have tried the post EDIT version, which definitely works for me